# Pre-install Wordpress Plugins

Tags: wordpress, plugins

I'm currently learning more about Wordpress, there's just one thing I wished to know that I couldn't seem to find anything about elsewhere. Let's say I have multiple clients who all want Wordpress installations. Is it possible to automatically install (pre-install) plugins alongside the initial WP install? The reason I'm asking this is because it would be much easier than manually installing them AFTER the WP install, considering I'll be doing this on over 100 of my clients websites.

I've looked into it and noticed something where a theme will automatically install plugins alongside it, I'm sure this could be a work-around too if my initial idea couldn't be done.

Anyone know anything/any method for this?

Thanks

Comment: This question is more fit to [wordpress.se], but I'm pretty sure this already has [interesting answers](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/deployment) over there; research before asking. Check the guides [ask] and [About].

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about Wordpress.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

good question. the easiest way to achieve this is to download the plugins to your computer, and add it to the websites through FTP all at once. If you want more info, I would be more than happy provide a detailed instruction=)

The reason some themes allow you to pre-install plugins is, because they are built from scratch. Wordpress has already been built and coded to do certain things, so if you want Wordpress to grab certain plugins when installed. You would have to download Wordpress 3.6 and manually code it to do this function.

I hope this answers your question, I am really sorry if it doesn't.

Comment: So it's as simple as just including them within the plugin directory before install? If you could explain more that would be best thanks. :)

Answer (score 1):

I believe this is what you're looking for: http://tgmpluginactivation.com/

> TGM Plugin Activation is a PHP library that allows you to easily
>   require or recommend plugins for your WordPress themes (and plugins).
>   It allows your users to install and even automatically activate
>   plugins in singular or bulk fashion using native WordPress classes,
>   functions and interfaces. You can reference pre-packaged plugins,
>   plugins from the WordPress Plugin Repository or even plugins hosted
>   elsewhere on the internet.